# Mocking Components with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, angular

I am trying to mock the Heroes-Component of the ['Tour of Heroes' Angular 2 Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/). But I don't know how to mock the router, which is needed for instantiating the HeroesComponent. I tried to create a Spy with Jasmine, but that doesn't work, because it is missing the property 'RootComponentType'.

How can I make this work?

```
import {HeroesComponent} from "./heroes.component";
import {Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";
import {HeroService} from "./hero.service";


describe('HeroesComponent', () => {
    let heroes:HeroesComponent;
    let router:Router;
    let service:HeroService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        router = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
        service = new HeroService(/* I will care about this later */);
        heroes = new HeroesComponent(router, service);
    });
    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(heroes).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

It is working now:

```
describe('HeroesComponent', () => {
    let router:any;
    let heroesComponent:HeroesComponent;
    let service:HeroService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        router = new class {
            navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate");
        };
        heroesComponent = new HeroesComponent(router, service);
    });
    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(heroesComponent).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a spy directly on a navigate method.

1. Using addProviders for DI:

   ```
   beforeEach(() => addProviders([
   { 
       provide: Router, 
       useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); }
   }]));
   ```
2. For a directly initialization of a component:

   ```
   let router;
   let heroesComponent;

   beforeEach(() => {
       router = new class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); };
       heroesComponent = new HeroesComponent(router);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I supply the HeroesComponent constructor with the provider?

Comment: @JoCa adjusted the answer accordingly.